# Should there be a question-answer ratio?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, users

I noticed there's a user with over 620 questions and just 1 answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/43907/gold

My understanding of Stack Overflow is that it should reward answers, not questions.  Should there be a minimum question-answer ratio to prevent this sort of situation?

Comment: If the questions are good, who cares? If anything, we need more people who can ask good questions.

Comment: And we don't want to force someone to answer questions if they don't feel they can give a good answer

Comment: His questions are probably helping a LOT of other people who research google for similar questions... what's the harm?

Comment: We *just* introduced badges to promote repeatedly asking well-received questions; we need **good** questions being asked, not a specific ratio.

Comment: If you look through them, most of his questions aren't particularly high in quality. I'm kinda surprised he's not blocked.

Comment: @codeMagic though anyone working in software development long enough to ask 620 questions must have learned enough to be perfectly capable of answering some questions adequately if they choose to.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this question?

Comment: @MartinSmith it would seem so but I haven't went through any of that person's questions. But we also aren't talking about a specific individual but the concept of a Q:A ratio. Which is a bad idea because "we don't want to force someone to answer questions if they don't feel they can give a good answer "

Comment: @stephen because people disagree with your statement. Voting on meta is different.

Comment: Not everything is what it seems.  That user has been suspended several times for asking poor questions.  Looks like he just got another one year to think it over, his prevision suspension was a year as well.  That worked, no need for a ratio :)

Comment: s/620/532/ right now.

Comment: The user has been suspended for a year for low quality contributions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think there should be a question/answer ratio enforced. There are already rate limits on asking questions and quality checks that lead to question bans (both scripted and manually handed out by moderators). This should be enough to filter out anyone leeching off of the site. If we force people to answer questions in order to ask them, there's a good chance we'll end up with a lot more low-quality answers in response.

Aside from all that, I don't think we want to slow down people like [Edward Tanguay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4639/edward-tanguay?tab=questions&sort=votes) from asking high-quality questions any more than we already do.

Comment: I was wondering how to deal with this same issue. For every Edward there is 100's of user's like this: http://stackoverflow.com/users/300675/user300675?tab=summary 243 questions, no answers, and most of the questions are worthless to anyone outside of this individual user... But I guess we'll all just have to live with it. If you try to answer a question that leads to growth - continuing to ask them and getting answers will not

Comment: @castling There are increasingly strict rate limits on asking questions before a block kicks in on users who repeatedly ask nothing but low-quality questions, so that slows them down. With enough closed questions they will eventually be stopped.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for explaining some of the 'behind the scenes' workings

Answer (score -3):

If the questions are good then that shouldn't be a problem. I get the difference in the amount, it's really hard to give an answer that actually gives points. Questions get responses in 5 mins, and they usually have the best posible answer.

You have to literally "hunt" the feed page for one that can help you get reputation.

Comment: Tip: In the more obscure tags, like [Forth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forth), there is more time to answer. In fact, [the latest question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895205) in that tag still hasn't received an answer 16 days after it was posed.

Comment: Thanks Peter i look it up. I got -2 for just giving my opinion lol.